# Azure data disk - Getting files from exported disk file

Tags: azure, vhd, azure-vm, azure-disk

I have recently done an azure disk export. This disk was attached as a data disk to one of my Linux VM. I had mounted one of my pods volume to this disk. Unfortunately, due to some problem with the environment, I am unable to re-mount my disk. Now, I want to take the backup of those files which are on the disk. I ran a disk export which downloaded a file with the name abcd without any extension. File with given properties: -

[image]

I am not sure if this is the correct VHD file. I tried mounting it on my local windows machine but didn't work. I am a developer and I don't have much experience with Azure Disks and VMs. Please suggest some ways that how can i retrieve files from this disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is as follows:

1. Spin up a new VM or use one of the existing VMs to mount the disk
2. Logon to the VM with the disk mounted in step 1. You should be able to see the file that you want to copy off the disk
3. You can use a tool such as AzCopy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) to copy the desired file off the disk

If you have addtional questions, please reach out to us at AzuredisksPM@microsoft.com

Aung Oo
PM, Azure Storage Engineering PM team
Microsoft Corporation